# Is PWM or voltage control the most efficient way to control a heating element?

Tags: pwm, control, heat

I am thinking about a heating controller for my electrically heated motorcycle coat.  It draws about 6 amps at 14V on my motorcycle.
My question is whether it is more efficient to drive a heating element by pulsing full power or just lower the voltage so that a constant but small current is drawn.

I am trying to determine whether it would be better to build a circuit (for example a 555 driving a FET) with which I could vary the duty cycle or just buy a variable buck converter from Ebay.
Not all of my motorcycles have that much spare generating capacity, so I would like to maximise how long I could run this for at a given level of heat output.

Apart from efficiency, could there be other issues such radio interference? I wouldn't think that higher frequencies would be helpful in this application, so a few Hertz would be all that is needed.

I know that I may be over-complicating this, but I am the kind of person that bores aluminium bolts for the weight saving; it adds up if you can do enough of it.

I am a beginner with electronics, have I missed a power control technique that would be more suitable?

Regards

Otto

Comment: Boring out your bolts also adds up on savings in terms of mean time between failure due to tensile limitations and early metal fatigue. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

A heater does not need a steady power input. PWM will be simpler than a buck regulator, and less inefficient as well (more heat in the jacket, less heat lost in the controller). Wait, why not put the PWM power control component in the jacket, and then no heat is wasted at all!

Comment: Why not connecting exhaust to the coat? Think about it, a system of thin long tubes, heat exchanger :D

Answer (score 0):

A buck-converter is a switching topology, and can be PWM driven, if well designed it will provide significant RFI reduction because the entirely load
will have a very low ripple (depends on the buck-converter).

But, this depends on the load information you don't said. Like you know, using a low frequency will help reducing switching losses, without affecting temperature regulation so much.

A non-switching design (linear), will be just moving the heat not used to other component to dissipate, so other than using only full load the switching design is the most efficient.